# Finding 'distance' between elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to solve an auto-cipher and to find the key length i need to find the 'distance' between all elements in the cipher-text.
I've found the distances between all elements in the array however i now want some way to find the frequency of each jump.
So for example, if i had a string "ababbababba" and wanted to work with a's, the frequency of jumps of 1 is 2 and the frequency of jumps of 2 is 2.

```
for(int i = 1; i<cipher2.length(); i++ ){
            if(cipher2Array[i] == 'f') {
                arrayList.add(i);
                int jumpDistance = arrayList.get(i) - arrayList.get(i-1);
            }
        }
```

So basically from here, with my jumpDistance variable, how would I something like

```
if(jumpDistance == theSameinAnyOtherPlaceOfArray) {
counter++;
}
```

And output a type of table with jumpSize, frequency

Comment: `Map<Character, Map<Integer, Integer>>` and `int[]` to maintain last look up value would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`. You can store the `jumpSize` as a key and the corresponding `frequency` as value.

Yet again if you want multiple characters to be eveluated at one go, you would need a nested Map ie - a map for each character `Map<Character, Map<Integer, Integer>>` as suggested by @SAM.

```
       Map<Integer, Integer> counter = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
       for(int i = 1; i<cipher2.length(); i++ ){
            if(cipher2Array[i] == 'f') {
                arrayList.add(i);
                int jumpDistance = arrayList.get(i) - arrayList.get(i-1);
                Integer freq = counter.get(jumpdistance);
                freq = freq == null ? 1 : freq+1;
                counter.put(jumpDistance, freq);
            }
        }
```